# how to create form based role in jsp servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jdbc

for example-there are two pages.
1.studentinfo and 2.marksinfo.
user1 has  admin role(create,edit record) of studentinfo page and user role(view only) of marksinfo page.
user2 has  admin role(create,edit record) of marksinfo page and user role(view only) of studenthow info page.
condition:- I neither want to  hardcode username and nor to create separate page.

Comment: People use Access Managers(Ping, OAM and etc.)  for such things. You will be able to grab request headers with values assigned to you or customer's profile. If you don't have it and don't want to hardcode it in jsp then you could create constant in your web application property files and pull the values from there, it is still considered some type of hardcoding but at least not inside java code an property file is very fast and convenient to modify(in comparison with jsp).

Comment: @Foxy I would like to maintain one form for user role with following feild:-1.username,2.password.3.formname.4.role(create,edit,read).by this form creation, role should be assigned to user for particular form.is it possible to do?

Comment: Yes, it i possible. Just create your form and put condition right before 4th field, for example, <% if(role.equalsIgnoreCase("admin")) {%><input type="button" value="Create/Edit"><%}else{%><input type="button" value="Read"><%}%>.